# How to access directory file outside django project

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to import files that are outside my Django folder, but I get the following error:

**No module named 'manage_db'**

**It's important to note** that I created this package on my local computer, so I don't need to do a pip install.

The path from which I want to make a call to the file is:

**api-yahoo-finance/yahoo/api_yahoo/views**

I want to import on the following form from the following path:

**from manage_db.exc_get_symbol import get_symbol**

And I want to import all the files on the package into the following folder:
whose path is manage_db and is outside the api-yahoo-finance folder
(On manage_db existing all the files that I want to import)

**Note: I work with Django Framework.**

Answer (score 0):

In the settings file, write:

```
import os

...

FILES_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(temp_parent, "../your_dest_package"))
```

Then in the views file, write:

```
from django.conf import settings

import os


file_path = os.path.join(settings.FILES_DIR, 'yourfile')
```